# How to correct sequence of time period and respective data in R?

Tags: r, date, sequence

I have data as given below (date is in yyyymmdd format). The problem is that data doesn't have proper sequence. For example, 20070801, 20070802... will appear after 20070615; later after many rows 20070616 will appear. Is it possible to correct the sequence of date and respective data in R? (While changing the sequence of dates, sequence of data corresponding to those dates also need to be changed).

```
Date       Max_Temp       Min_Temp       Avg_Temp  
20060101       27       20       18
20060102       29       22       16
..       ..       ..       ..
..       ..       ..       ..
..       ..       ..       ..
..       ..       ..       ..
20161231       18       10       12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the order of *Date* with `order` after conversion to *Date* class, then using the sequence to index the original data

```
df[order(as.Date(as.character(df$Date), format="%Y%m%d")), ]
      Date Max_Temp Min_Temp Avg_Temp
4 20060101        1        2       18
6 20060102       22       19       18
5 20060104        4        4       18
2 20060119       29       22       16
1 20070101       27       20       18
3 20161231       18       10       12
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c(20070101, 20060119, 20161231, 20060101, 
20060104, 20060102), Max_Temp = c(27L, 29L, 18L, 1L, 4L, 22L), 
    Min_Temp = c(20L, 22L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 19L), Avg_Temp = c(18L, 
    16L, 12L, 18L, 18L, 18L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why not just `df[order(df$Date), ]`, or `df[order(as.integer(df$Date)), ]`?

Comment: @jay.sf You’re right, works too in this case. I did the date conversion in parts to be consistent with the date class but also to get a proper sorting even when the date order is e.g. day month year. In this case it only requires a format change or a *tryFormats*.

Comment: I see what you did, and it's very safe. Even if it would be date class you can use integer date, try `order(seq.Date(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 10, 1))`. The `as.integer` would care for character class. It would fail if the date was imperial, but that would not be scientific anyway.

Comment: @jay.sf Very true. I guess that's why I like R. There're always several clever ways to approach a problem ;)